# Opposite of lowering

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "lowering", as in the context of lowering something, therefore making it lower in some measurable way, is pretty common.

It is so common that I often start sentences about doing the opposite, and get to the specific word, and it's completely blank. I have no idea what word could mean "making something higher according to some scale that is probably obvious in context".

What word would be good for this situation? I'm pretty sure "highering" is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Raising* is used in the physical sense of lifting an item, but it's also used figuratively in the same way as *lowering*. For example a recipe might instruct you to *raise the temperature*.

Answer (score 1):

also, increase can be used.
but check the antonyms to find the best one: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lower

Comment: I think increase only works for making amounts higher, but wouldn't work for certain cases like putting an object higher spatially, like a plane flying higher

Comment: yes, it depends on the context, and how exactly you want to use the word.

Comment: increasing is the opposite of decreasing though?